# Intersect two columns of the same table with lists/STUFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, intersect

I created a table with the following structure in sql server:

| id | pertinent | procedure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13271,13272,513008,513009 | 13200,13271,19353,21101,21105,21140 |
| 2 | 18236 | 18235,19290,19749,21102,21105,21140 |

And I want to make an intersect between pertinent and procedure, and have the following result:

| id | pertinent | procedure | procedures pertinents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13271,13272,513008,513009 | 13200,13271,19353,21101,21105,21140 | 13271 |
| 2 | 18236 | 18235,19290,19749,21102,21105,21140 | NULL |

But i haven't figure it out how can i iterate it or split it in sql, any ideas? thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: If you had a normalised design, this would be trivial... Why not fix your design?

Comment: @squillman is 12.0.6118.4

Comment: @Larnu, it's the design they need. So not trivial for me.

Comment: So not a version with `STRING_SPLIT` *or* `STRING_AGG` (assuming that you need to reaggregate your string if there are multiple matches). This further cements that fixing the design is a must.

Comment: *"it's the design they need."* Do you really mean "need"; I suspect what you mean it's "want". If they really "need" it, I'd love to know why they need a denormalised and unperformant design.

Comment: Whenever just pulling some data out of the database is complicated it is almost always an indication that the design is lacking in normalization. In this case it violates 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. That makes this kind of thing way more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: If these delimited values were actually *rows* in two separate tables then they could be intersected as a *set* which is what relational databases do best; comma separated values have no place in a relational database (if you want to actually work with the data and not just retrieve it verbatim).

Comment: To work with the data you have, and in the quite old version of SQL Server you'll need to use a combination of charindex and a tally table to split the values into two sets of rows (emulating how the data should be stored), then join these two sets to find common values, and (possibly, unknown), re-combine 1 or more rows back into a single string using *for xml*.

Comment: With all your comments I check way back the code and did the intersect back then and it was more easy than with the list now. Thanks for all the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to normalize the database to 1NF, having one value per tuple. Then you'd have two tables, one called pertinent, with 5 rows, and one called procedure, with 12 rows. After that, a simple SELECT statement with a JOIN between these tables would suffice, producing the desired results.

As others have mentioned, this would be unnecessarily hard to do on this table in this quite old version of SQL Server. Since a schema normalization is probably the best, modernizing the database at the same time might be a good call. Some popular choices would be Postgres and Snowflake, and my personal favorite is SingleStore.